I have a list of data in column F that I want to move into Columns A-D
I have a list of data in Column F, Cell 1: name,Cell 2: address,Cell 3:city,Cell 4: ID. I want to move the data to Columns A-D. Column A:Name, Column B: Address, Column C: City, Column D: ID.
I tried putting in column A cell 2: =f1, column B cell 2: =f2, column C cell 2: =f3, column C cell 2: =f4. Then trying to drag the bottom right corner of the cell to make it dynamic both vertically and horizontally but it doesn fill out the cells correctly. Column A cell 3 should be =f5 but it filled it with f2. Column B cell 3 should be =f6 but it filled it with =f3




A
B
C
D
E
F




1
Name
Address
City
Short ID

Company 1


2
Company 1
2222 al street
Blue cheese
1

2222 al street


3
2222 al   street
Blue cheese
1
Company 2

Blue cheese


4
Blue   cheese
1
Company 2
1111 arm rd

1


5





Company 2


6





1111 arm rd


7





Ranch


8





2


9





Company 3


10





3333 raindrop drive


11





Peanut


12





3




Try =WRAPROWS(F1:F12,4).

Stop with column, cell, and refer to them properly: A1, B1, F1, D3, etc. It's not only less typing, it's easier to read and understand, and is the normal way to reference cells in spreadsheets. So you have something in F1 that you want to move to A1, in G1 that you want to move to B1, and so forth.

And the way you are trying, it will not work, do it in this way: for the first two rows enter as : DLF1 Till DLF4 and in the second row DLF5 till DLF8, next hold down the two rows and fill down, press CTRL+H replace DL with =. DL is nothing but stands for Derek Long and you can use any other names or words etc.

Thank you all for the help! I ended up using the wraprows suggestion from @VBasic2008

You could try this simple trick.



Firstly, enter DLF1 in cell A2 and fill right till D2 --> ensure it is sequential.  (DLF1,DLF2,DLF3,DLF4) 
In the second row in cell A3 enter DLF5 and fill right till D3 --> ensure it is sequential.  (DLF5,DLF6,DLF7,DLF8) 
Now, select both the rows and fill down, as far as you need.
Press CTRL+H --> Find What: --> DL --> Replace With: --> =  --> Click Replace All --> OK. Done. Refer the .gif


Using Excel Formulas depending on your Excel Version could try any one of the followings:


=WRAPROWS(TOCOL(F:F,1),4)


Or, This works from Excel 2021+ onwards
=INDEX(F:F,SEQUENCE(COUNTA(F:F)/4,4))


Or, This will work from Excel 2010+ onwards.
=IFERROR(INDEX($F$1:$F$12,COLUMNS($A$1:A1)+(ROWS(A$1:A1)-1)*4),"")



What about this?

Formula in cell A2 is:
=INDEX($F$1:$F$12;(ROW()-2)*4+COLUMN())

Just drag to right and drag down
Notice this formula will work only if your input is exactly sortered as the example provided.
Anyways, if you got Excel365, inded what @VBasic2008 provided in comment should work!
